# Problemas con interpolacion Kriging

Tags: python, python-3.x, estadística

he estado practicando la interpolacion con Kriging y me da el resultado que da la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los puntos que se resaltan, son los puntos coordenados con la variable a estudiar, pero en todos los ejercicios que he observado no presenta estos puntos.

Trabajé con PyKrige

```
ok = OrdinaryKriging(x,y,valor, variogram_model='gaussian', nlags=30,
                    variogram_parameters= {'sill': var1, 'range': 500, 'nugget': 100000}, enable_plotting=True,
                    coordinates_type='euclidean')
```

He ingresado en sill, el valor de la varianza ya que leí que ese es el valor que corresponde.

Me pregunto que estaré haciendo mal, como observación puedo decir que los valores, a estudiar, fueron creados aleatoriamente.